# Blob ID sequence

Tags: c#, image-processing, aforge, accord.net

Im using A-forge with c# to extract and process blobs from an image. Everything works great except blob numbering(ID). Currently, aforge randomly assigns a blob ID to each blob. I have blobs in a pattern and I want to number the blob from left to right. There are seperate processes in my program which handles the blob information, they expect a particular blob with the particular ID at the same place everytime. How do I do this?

Please help.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7vZL.png)

Comment: Can you use a dictionary<id, blob> to abstract it away?

Comment: Hi, can you please elaborate. I dont quite understand how to use a dictionary using blob information.